# I think this error is not the code rather it is in the setting somewhere

Tags: types, boolean, constants, expression, autofocus

it gives me something like this.

```
/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart:1951:9: Error: Not a constant expression.
  final bool? autofocus;
        ^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart:2001:11: Error: 'bool' isn't a type.
    final bool alwaysUse24HourFormat = MediaQuery.alwaysUse24HourFormatOf(context);
          ^^^^
    final bool alwaysUse24HourFormat = MediaQuery.alwaysUse24HourFormatOf(context);
          ^^^^
/C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/user_accounts_drawer_header.dart:82:9: Error: Not a constant expression.
  final bool isOpen;
        ^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

I remove something I think.

Comment: Could you please share the content of user_accounts_drawer_header ? I believe that you used bool as an identifier somewhere.